# Help Keeping Audio Lesson Playlists separate from Music

Tags: ipod, playlist

I am trying to sort out the music on my iPod into play lists, the thing is I have a bunch of playlists that are audio lessons which I'd like to appear after the music playlists.

I know if I put the same special character before them they will all appear at the start of the list, but I'd like to make them appear at the end of the list. Is there a character tha my iPod/iTunes, will put after z?

Alternatively is there a way to have these MP3's listed as podcasts so that they don't clutter my music and I can keep track of which lessons I've listened to?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can make those audio lessons appear as podcasts. In iTunes, right click your song(s) and select **Get info** (or <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>). On the **Options** tab, change the **Media Kind** to  **Podcast**.

[image: How to change media kind to Podcast]

The appearance is slightly different when selecting multiple songs, but is very straight forward

Comment: I did this and they seem to have disaperd off the music section of iTunes but they aren't in the podcasts section either. Some of them were already in a playlist and they are in that playlist, but some lessions I hadn't put into a play list have disapered in their entirety...